# LinkedHashSet Not Removing Duplicates

Tags: java, coordinates, hashcode, no-duplicates, linkedhashset

I am trying to create a search algorithm that stores coordinate pairs in a wrapper class called HashSquareSpec. In order to avoid duplicates, and maintain insertion order, I am inserting each HashSquareSpec into a LinkedHashSet. Even though I have overridden the equals() method and hashCode() methods, the LinkedHashSet still accepts two HashSquareSpec objects with
the same coordinate pairs.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    LinkedHashSet<HashSquareSpec> firedShots = new HashLinkedSet<HashSquareSpec>();
    HashSquareSpec a = new HashSquareSpec(1,2);
    HashSquareSpec b = new HashSquareSpec(2,2);
    HashSquareSpec c = new HashSquareSpec(1,2);
    HashSquareSpec d = new HashSquareSpec(3,2);

    firedShots.add(a);
    firedShots.add(b);
    firedShots.add(c);
    firedShots.add(d);
    System.out.println(a.equals((SquareSpec)c));
    Iterator l = firedShots.iterator();
    while(l.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(l.next().hashCode());
    }
}

Output:
true
38444474
38474265
38444474
38504056
```

HashSquare class

```
public class HashSquareSpec extends SquareSpec 
{
  public HashSquareSpec(int sx, int sy) 
  {
    super(sx,sy);
  }

  public HashSquareSpec(String codeString) 
  {
    super(codeString);
  }

  @Override  
  public int hashCode() 
  {  
    return this.toString().hashCode();  
  }  

  public boolean equals(HashSquareSpec other) 
  {
    if(this.toString().equals(other.toString()))
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
}
```

and the super class of HashSquareSpec

```
public class SquareSpec {
  public int x;
  public int y;

  public SquareSpec(int sx, int sy) {
      this.x = sx; 
      this.y = sy;
  }

  public SquareSpec(String codeString) {
      this.x = Integer.parseInt(codeString.substring(1,2));
      this.y = Integer.parseInt(codeString.substring(3,4));
  }

  public String toString() {
      return("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
  }

  public boolean equals(SquareSpec other) {
      return (other.x == this.x  && 
              other.y == this.y );
    }
  }
```

Despite many different hashCode variations and Eclipse equals and hashCode generation, the
firedShots data structure keeps accepting duplicates. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track, overriding `hashcode` and `equals`, except you are incorrectly overriding the [`equals` method from `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) in `HashSquareSpec` (and `SquareSpec`).  The parameter must be an `Object`.  Because it's not overridden, `equals` from `Object` is called, which compares object references to see if they're the same object.  They aren't, so the "duplicate" is allowed.

Try:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) 
{
  if(this.toString().equals(other.toString()))
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

You should also test if `other` is `null` and then ensure that `other` is the same type.

Include the `@Override` annotation so that the compiler will complain if the method doesn't actually override anything.

Comment: This isn't a good `equals` implementation either; you should be doing the `instanceof` check.  (For example, your implementation isn't symmetric, because this will `equal` a `String`.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Very true, which is why included a sentence about null-checking and checking if `other` is of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

It's still accepting because you are not overriding the `equals` method. You need to override `boolean equals(Object)`. The problem is that you're defining a new method like `boolean equals(SquareSpec)`.

Here is the method that `LinkedHashSet#add(T)` eventually invokes:

`HashMap#put(K, V)`:

```
@Override public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null) {
        return putValueForNullKey(value);
    }

    int hash = secondaryHash(key.hashCode());
    HashMapEntry<K, V>[] tab = table;
    int index = hash & (tab.length - 1);
    for (HashMapEntry<K, V> e = tab[index]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        if (e.hash == hash && key.equals(e.key)) {
            preModify(e);
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            return oldValue;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it compares using `hashCode` and `equals(Object)`.